# How to perform CRUD in seperate page in Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-ui-mvc

Kendo supports inline, batch and popup . But i want to edit, create and delete operations in separate pages. Please any suggestions on how to do?

Comment: if you don't want to use the inbuilt features of the grid to do this on the same page wouldn't you just use the standard mvc methods of navigating over to another page as per the usual number of beginner tutorials. Just out of interest why do you want to do these operations elsewhere away from the page that has your grid (assuming that's what   you are referring too)?

Comment: Because i have lot of fields in the grid, so i am showing only important fields on the grid and when user clicks on view details he can see all the details and click new he can enter all the details so i want to take it to next page where he can give all the details rather inline or popup.

Comment: You could just add a button/link in the grid that will navigate away to the next page. This may help you with customising the toolbar: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/toolbar-template. if you want it on each row then you would need to add clientTemplating to a column on the rows that would navigate away to these actions. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/toolbar-template if you need something a little more specific I can try and get a dojo up for you later on today. Are you using the wrappers or pure html/javascript approach?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks a lot for the help and advise. I will try and will ask you if i struck at some place :)

Comment: Hi david, I am doing customcommand for the edit for each row. But i am not able to get the selected column id. I am getting record object as null. Please help. I have tired making grid selectable too                                                   columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").SendDataKeys(true).Click("editClick"));        'function editClick(e) {     
        e.preventDefault();
        var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');               
        var record = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); 
        alert(record);
        var id = record.Id;
        alert(id);'

Comment: Ok. I will get a dojo up later today for you. Hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: here is a quick dojo. Hopefully it shows you what you are trying to achieve.  http://dojo.telerik.com/ACuNa/2 any issues let me know. Or if you need the MVC Wrapper equivalent I can do that but it will take me a bit longer to do.